# How to get first occurrence of a word in big string and print the whole word between delimiter

Tags: java

I have a string as

```
abc: text||something mnamed||abc:text2||something name2||abc:text3
```

I want to print the value between the delimiter when ever this string occurs very first time "`abc:`"
As we can see here `abc:` occurrence in the string 3 times but i want the data when ever it occurred very first time in that string
For the above exampe my output should be ======>> `abc: text`
FOR

```
something mnamed||abc:text2||something name2||abc: text||something name2||abc:text3
```

output should be=====>>`abc:text2`
FOR

```
   something mnamed||something name2||abc:text3||abc:text2||something mnamed
output should be=======>> abc:text3
```

Comment: We're not doing your homework for you. Post your attempted code and we'll nudge you in the right direction

Comment: @JoshEvans As you can see you were wrong, the greed for reputation "forces" people to do homework for free (but I agree with you, that this shouldn't happen).

Comment: @Tom But the stand for honesty can hold the people from being "forced"..join hands ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the string by `||`, filter the substrings starting with `abc:` and take the first one:

```
String str = "something mnamed||abc:text2||something name2||etc...";
String result = 
    Arrays.stream(str.split("\\|\\|"))
          .filter(s -> s.startsWith("abc:"))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Although you've solved his problem, he's not going to learn anything from copy-and-pasting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many valid approaches for solving this problem, using regular expression is probably among the most expedient ones.

Start by looking for an occurrence of `"abc:"` followed by a sequence that terminates in `||`, or reaches the end of the input. Capturing this sequence produces the desired result.

The only tricky issue here is finding double bars `||` while allowing single bars `|` inside the text. This can be done by the following expression: `([^|]|[|](?![|]))*`

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/1zlrKn/1)

Using the expression above with [Java regex library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is left to the reader as a straightforward learning exercise.